# How to make scheduled post preview visible to anyone?

Tags: publish, previews

When I write a post and schedule it for later publishing, WordPress will allow me to preview the post as if it was already published but I need to be logged in as administrator (or anyone who is authorized to preview the post).

Is there a way, possibly a query string parameter, to make the post previewable by anyone, i.e. also by anonymous users? Something like `my-post?previewsecret=645732116468`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Draft previews

Take a quick look at this chunk of core code in *query.php* which

> [Checks] post status to determine if post should be displayed.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/query.php#L2658

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
  // User must be logged in to view unpublished posts.
  $this->posts = array();
}
```

...is what makes it somewhat non-straightforward to bypass for non logged in users. You could override the result of that function by going [deeper](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L715) and then taking care of roles. But that's too much overhead and can contribute to exposed security.

If you look a little further up http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/query.php#L2632 on line 2632 you'll find that the post is actually fetched from the database and can be further filtered using the `posts_results` hook that comes a couple of lines lower.

Store the value of the post, and inject it towards the end after all the checks that void the `posts` array. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/query.php#L2740 where `the_posts` hook is eagerly awaiting.

So something rough would look like:

```
add_filter( 'posts_results', 'wpse46014_peek_into_private', null, 2 );
function wpse46014_peek_into_private( $posts, &$query ) {

    if ( sizeof( $posts ) != 1 ) return $posts; /* not interested */

    $status = get_post_status( $posts[0] );
    $post_status_obj = get_post_status_object( $status );

    if ( $post_status_obj->public ) return $posts; /* it's public */

    if ( !isset( $_GET['key'] ) || $_GET['key'] != 'foryoureyesonly' )
        return $posts; /* not for your eyes */

    $query->_my_private_stash = $posts; /* stash away */

    add_filter( 'the_posts', 'wpse46014_inject_private', null, 2 );
}

function wpse46014_inject_private( $posts, &$query ) {
    /* do only once */
    remove_filter( 'the_posts', 'wpse46014_inject_private', null, 2 );
    return $query->_my_private_stash;
}
```

Append your post preview link with the secret key `?p=4601&key=foryoureyesonly` and the post is displayed for anyone. The code has some dirty going-ons, like the stash, you can use `globals` instead (not recommended), or wrap it up into an object (yes!) and further extend the functionality with custom passwords for each post, etc.

### Scheduled previews

Scheduled previews work in a very similar way. The `posts_results` are populated with `'future'` status posts in absolutely the same fashion and the same hooks can be leveraged. The code will work without change for scheduled posts.

`/2012/07/12/one-two-three/` - `404 NOT FOUND`

`/2012/07/12/one-two-three/?key=foryoureyesonly` - `200 OK`

Answer (score 1):

Soulseekah's answer is incredible, and the exact thing I was looking for. In searching for this, I also came across a plugin (that might be based off this post for all I know).

[Public Post Preview](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/public-post-preview/)